# parsing issue with JSON data from SQL 2017 to MongoDB

Tags: json, sql-server, mongodb

I am working on c# utility to migrate data from SQL server 2017 to MongoDB. Below are steps I am following

1) Getting data from SQL server in JSON format (FOR JSON AUTO)
2) Parsing into BSON document
3) Then trying to insert into MongoDB

But I am getting error while reading JSON data from SQL.

My Json data is combination of root attributes as well as nested objects.

So Its dynamic data, that I want to PUSH as it is to MongoDB.

```
string jsonData = string.Empty;
            foreach (var userId in userIdList)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_GetUserdata", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userId;

                        con.Open();

                        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
                        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (!reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            jsonResult.Append("[]");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0));
                                jsonData = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\a.txt", jsonResult.ToString());
                                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\a.txt",jsonData);

                                jsonData.TrimEnd(']');
                                jsonData.TrimStart('[');

                                //Create client connection to our MongoDB database
                                var client = new MongoClient(MongoDBConnectionString);

                                //Create a session object that is used when leveraging transactions
                                var session = client.StartSession();

                                //Create the collection object that represents the "products" collection
                                var employeeCollection = session.Client.GetDatabase("mongodev").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("EmpData");

                                //Begin transaction
                                session.StartTransaction();

                                try
                                {
                                    dynamic resultJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

                                    var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(resultJson);
                                    //MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document
                                    //    = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonResult);

                                    employeeCollection.InsertOneAsync(document);

                                    //BsonArray pipeline =
                                    //    MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(jsonData);

                                    //var documents = pipeline.Select(val => val.AsBsonDocument);
                                    //employeeCollection.InsertManyAsync(documents);

                                    session.CommitTransaction();


                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                                    session.AbortTransaction();
                                    throw;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I can't help you here, but you state you receive an error? Posting that error is going to be really important for the volunteers here.

Comment: *"1) Getting data from SQL server in JSON format..."* - Why? Why not simply connect to the SQL server via driver, run your queries into native data structures and use those data structures to insert to MongoDB? You are basically doing all of that, with the exception of "dumping to JSON" for no logical reason other than you seem to think you need to do this. You don't.